# Error [ReferenceError]: navigator is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, chalk

So I am using NextJS v13.5.4 and chalk v5.3.0. This is the error that I am getting when I am logging in my next middleware.

```
 ⨯ Error [ReferenceError]: navigator is not defined
    at <unknown> (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/chalk/source/vendor/supports-color/browser.js:6)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/chalk/source/vendor/supports-color/browser.js:6:5)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/chalk/source/vendor/supports-color/browser.js:16:3)
    at (middleware)/./node_modules/chalk/source/vendor/supports-color/browser.js (file://D:\projects\munchies\v2\Munchies-website-app\.next\server\src\middleware.js:1267:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (file://D:\projects\munchies\v2\Munchies-website-app\.next\server\edge-runtime-webpack.js:37:33)
    at fn (file://D:\projects\munchies\v2\Munchies-website-app\.next\server\edge-runtime-webpack.js:280:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/chalk/source/index.js:18:73)
    at (middleware)/./node_modules/chalk/source/index.js (file://D:\projects\munchies\v2\Munchies-website-app\.next\server\src\middleware.js:1234:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (file://D:\projects\munchies\v2\Munchies-website-app\.next\server\edge-runtime-webpack.js:37:33)
    at fn (file://D:\projects\munchies\v2\Munchies-website-app\.next\server\edge-runtime-webpack.js:280:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./src/libs/axios/index.ts:11:63) {
  middleware: true
}
```

I found a similar issue in rollup bundler, which is [this](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/issues/598).
I think webpack is doing something similar or else. I am no expert in webpack. So anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: try to use `window.navigator`

Comment: @YuvarajM where?

Comment: try to use the `ansis` instead of the chalk. The ansis is 100% compatible with chalk, but is smaller, faster and you can use named import of using styles.

Comment: not using chalk is not possible now tbh.